# Apache-Weblogic 404 configuration

Tags: apache2, weblogic-10.x, custom-error-pages

I've searched around for this quite a bit and found similar questions but not exactly the same, but nonetheless I apologize if this is a duplicate question.

Basically, I am trying to handle HTTP error responses (i.e. 404) with a custom error page (i.e. 404.html) when my application is down, but weblogic is still up.

I am using Apache 2.2 with the weblogic module. I have set the ErrorDocument directive for Apache as well as the ErrorPage parameter within the  block.

I have also set the  location within my web.xml for my application, but this question is for when the application is down.

Currently, when the app is down and weblogic is running I am getting the weblogic default 404 page. How can I force apache and/or weblogic to use my custom page?

Here is a sample of one variation of the config that I have tried.

```
 <IfModule mod_weblogic.c>
    WebLogicCluster host:port,host:port
    KeepAliveEnabled ON
    WLProxySSL OFF
    Debug ALL
    ErrorPage http://host:port/errors/errorSystem.html
</IfModule>
```

I can access the error page directly, but traffic is never forwarded on error.

I've also tried to set the ErrorPage to a relative url which is the ideal solution.

Comment: BarbiePylon - if the answer was helpful for you - upvote it please. If if was the solution - upvote + accept

Comment: Your solution won't work, he said he already tried... 3rd parapgraph

Comment: I'm real bad when it comes to http servers, but I do think this would help a little, it was the most complete topic I found: http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=4054&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=0

Comment: I tried following the solution posted there but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

The explanation from [apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html) do it also with samples of code:

```
ErrorDocument 500 http://xxx/
ErrorDocument 404 /Lame_excuses/not_found.html
ErrorDocument 401 /Subscription/how_to_subscribe.html
```

Comment: As I stated in the questions, I have already tried this and it doesn't work.

Comment: @BarbiePylon - where have you started with it? Did you show us your links? If you mean "I've searched around for this quite a bit and found similar questions but not exactly the same.." its too generally to understand what you have really tried and what not

Comment: @BarbiePylon a bit too late as I see

Answer (score 0):

According to WebLogic documentation, with ErrorPage parameter, *"The plug-in redirects to an error page when the back-end server returns an HTTP 503/Service Unavailable response and there are no servers for failover."*.

So 404 error from WebLogic will **not** be redirected to our custom error page specified with ErrorPage parameter.

The workaround is to create a simple webapp and deploy it onto your WebLogic. In this webapp:

1. in [**web.xml**] Specifiy your custom error code and page mappings, e.g.:

   <error-page>
     <error-code>404</error-code>
     <location>/errors/404.html</location>
   </error-page>
2. in [**weblogic.xml**] State that your context-root is '/':

   <weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     **<context-root>/</context-root>**
   </weblogic-web-app>
3. Your need to have error pages in place such as in '/errors' folder of you webapp.

Note that the '*FMW Welcome Page Application*' might have already been deployed and using '/' as context-root in your WebLogic domain. If that is the case, I believe it is safe to undeploy it or untarget it, but you are advised to raise a SR to product support asking whether it is hardful to do so.

Comment: I'm not sold this solution would work if you were navigating to the context path of a different webapp. Wouldn't you still just get the weblogic 404? Regardless, I appreciate the response but this is not a solution that we would implement. Its the best answer so far and if it works I would be more than happy to mark this as the answer! I'll try to test it later today.

Comment: If you webapp (i mean those whose context-root is not '/') is up and active, the error page works as usual. In other words, if "error-page" is configured in this specific webapp's web.xml, you hit your specific/custom error page; if not, you hit weblogic default error page.
If you webapp is down, your hit your error page specified in the webapp whose context-root is '/'.

Comment: I understand that this is not an optimal solution. Nontheless it looks like both Tomcat and Jetty allows us to specify global web.xml settings, but I haven't been able to find out how to do this in WebLogic, sorry. :( Please share with me if you find a more elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry...still haven't found a good solution. What's the stackoverflow convention for answers like this? Should I accept it since its a working solution even though its not a solution that I'll be able to use?